# Clean generic way of highlighting an active button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to highlight one of three buttons. I'm not very happy with the way I'm currently doing it, so I'd like to ask you for a few tipps.

I have three buttons that should be active regarding to the filter I'm using: My tickets, Team tickets and a specific user's tickets.

```
# tickets_controller.rb

@filter_by_user_id_active = Array.new
ba = %w(btn-default btn-primary)

# Determine, which button to highlight
if @user == current_user
  @filter_by_user_id_active[0] = ba[1]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[1] = ba[0]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[2] = ba[0]
elsif @user != nil && @user != current_user
  @filter_by_user_id_active[0] = ba[0]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[1] = ba[0]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[2] = ba[1]
else
  @filter_by_user_id_active[0] = ba[0]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[1] = ba[1]
  @filter_by_user_id_active[2] = ba[0]
end
```

And in the view:

```
= link_to "?user_id=#{current_user.id}", {:type => "button",
:class => "btn #{@filter_by_user_id_active[0]}"} do
My tickets
```

The other links use `[1]` and `[2]`

This is one of the links. The controller is return either `btn-default` or `btn-primary` based on the conditions. But I find, that this is not clean and generic code.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One simpler way can be like this one

```
ba = %w(btn-default btn-primary)    
@filter_by_user_id_active = [ba[0],ba[0],ba[0]]


if @user == current_user
  @filter_by_user_id_active[0] = ba[1]
elsif @user.present?
  @filter_by_user_id_active[2] = ba[1]
else
  @filter_by_user_id_active[1] = ba[1]
end
```

But If I have to do it then I wont add this class decision in controller or standalone logic in view. Instead I would do something Like:

```
= link_to "?user_id=#{current_user.id}", {:type => "button",
:class => "btn #{@user==current_user ? "btn-primary" : 'btn-default'}"} do
My tickets
end
```

Similarly for other two links same logic just condition change like `@user != current_user` or `@user.blank?`

**UPDATE**

You can define a helper method for this whole button thing like

```
def link_to_tickets url , text,active_class_condition
    link_to url, {:type => "button",:class => "btn #{active_class_condition ? "btn-primary" : 'btn-default'}"} do
        text
    end
end
```

then call this method in your views

```
=link_to_tickets "?user_id=#{current_user.id}" , "My Tickets" , @user == current_user
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I nearly overlooked that it could be minified to your provided code. I was hoping to transform it into something more generic, but this is at least cleaner than my code.

Comment: I have added another approach to do the same task. It's upto  you what you like :)

Comment: I had something like that in my view, but I felt uncomfortable for having too much ruby code in my view. I'll sleep on the matter :) Thanks.

Comment: Please look at the 3rd suggestion. I hope you will like it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to avoid doing that kind of logic in the controller. And another possible solution could be this, in your view:

```
= link_to "?user_id=#{current_user.id}", {:type => "button", :class => "btn #{link_class(0)}"} do
```

and in your **(whatever)_helper.rb** you could do this:

```
def link_class(index)
  return 'btn-primary' if @user == current_user && index == 0
  return 'btn-primary' if @user && @user != current_user && index == 2
  return 'btn-primary' if index == 1
  'btn-default' 
end
```

use *index* at your will. And the rest of the links would do the same, just pass the right *index*. You could also put all the *primary* *return*s in one line using *or*s, but that would look not as readable as it is in the example.

**UPDATE:** a simplified version of the function would be this:

```
def link_class(index)
  return 'btn-primary' if @user && [0,2].include?(index) || index == 1
  'btn-default' 
end
```

*[0, 2].include?(index)* is because those two need the *@user* to be present, *index == 1* does not need it.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution could be this:

```
ba = %w(btn-default btn-primary)
@filter_by_user_id_active = Array.new(3){ba[0]}
```

> No need to update all buttons every time

```
if @user == current_user
  @filter_by_user_id_active[0] = ba[1]
elsif @user.present?
  @filter_by_user_id_active[2] = ba[1]
else
  @filter_by_user_id_active[1] = ba[1]
end
```